# How do I turn off New Output notifications from iTerm2

Tags: iterm

I turned on iTerm2 shell integration to get notifications for long running commands, but I also get these notifications: [image]

I don't want them, how do I disable them without disabling iTerm2 Shell Integration completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck 'Send "New Output" alert" in iTerm2 settings :

Profile > {your profile} > Notifications > Filter Alerts button

[image: iTerm2 Notifications settings]